# How to UPDATE and DELETE queries with single OleDbCommand

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio

Im using excel file as database and access directly using OLEDB

using code below I can select to fill dataset and show it to gridview, aslo can add value using insert sql command below

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    ...
     cn.Open()
        With cm
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "insert into [Sheet$] values ('" & Textbox1.Text & "','" & Textbox2.Text & "')"
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
     cn.Close()
```

but for delete and update these method not working

```
.CommandText = delete from [Sheet$] where No='" & Textbox3.text & "'"
```

how can I fix this or maybe there is better way to access